# Windows 8 Hyper-V - how to give VM internet access?

Tags: network-adapter, windows-8, hyper-v

I've got Windows 8 Pro on my home machine. I want to have a Windows 7 Professional VM running under Hyper-V, and I want the VM to have full internet access. My physical machine has a wireless network adapter I use to connect to a router.

Here's what I've done so far:

- In Hyper-V Manager, I've created a new External Virtual Switch, which is connected to my wireless network adapter. If I look in Windows 8's Network Connections page, I can see it's created a virtual ethernet adapter and a network bridge, and my wireless adapter is now bridged.
- I've created a Windows 7 VM, and in the Hyper-V settings I've set it to use the virtual switch.

When I log into the VM, I have a network, but it's "unidentified" and has no internet access. What am I missing? Is it something to do with the "VLAN identification" settings? I'm not quite sure what these are about.

---

> This question was a **[Super User Question of the Week](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/tagged/question-of-the-week)**.
>   Read the **[blog entry](http://blog.superuser.com/2012/09/17/super-user-review-of-hyper-v-for-windows-8/)** for more details or **[contribute to the blog](http://blog.superuser.com/contribute/)** yourself

Comment: @Kronos - How & where in Windows 8.1 can one assign a Static IP to the Host Machine (with an External Virtual Switch)? It was easy to do so with the HV VM, but the static IP on the Physical Host Adapter seems to be gone and cant use it to access Host via RDP anymore. Direction please?

Answer (score 284, accepted):

In order to get the VM connected to the internet you have to tie it to the Ethernet/Wireless NIC Card.  In order to do this you have to create a "Virtual Switch".

1. Open your Hyper-V Manager
2. Select `Action` --> `Virtual Switch Manager`

   [image: Accessing the VM Switch Manager]
3. Select `External` and then `Create Virtual Switch`

   [image: Virtual Switch Manager]
4. Give the Switch a Name and then select the External Controller you use to connect to the internet (Ethernet, or Wireless NIC, etc,.)

   **Note**: You must select the way that you are actually connecting to the internet. IE, if your computer is set up to use Wifi or Ethernet, but is currently using Ethernet, you **must** use Ethernet - the Wifi connection will not work because the host machine isn't currently using it.

   [image: VM Switch Properties]
5. Select `Apply` and then `OK`
6. Right click on the Virtual Machine you want to connect and select `Settings`

   [image: VM Settings]
7. Under the `Network Adapter` Setting select the newly created Virtual Switch

[image: Connecting the Switch to the VM]

This should enable the connection you use to connect to the internet to be accessible to the VM

---

*Note: you may have to do a `ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew` (Windows) or a `sudo dhclient -v -r` and `sudo dhclient -v` (Linux) on the remote machine to get it to renew its DHCP settings and retrieve an IP address.*

Comment: This is a great description, but it's exactly what I did. I did manage to get it all working though, I'll check at home this evening and either add an answer or mark someone as correct.

Comment: Not exactly sure how I got it working, I think I'd ticked the "Enable virtual LAN identification" box and then unticked it whilst the VM was running - for some settings like this, the VM needs to be off/restarted to take effect.

Comment: i had to uninstall virtualpc2007 otherwise my physical network stopped working after step4/5

Comment: works flawlessly!!! so nice of you for great answer.

Comment: This procedure installed a network bridge under "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections". Every time I boot the VM I have to disable then enable the bridge (via its right-click menu). I've read similar accounts from others. Hope they get it ironed out.

Comment: Anyone looking for the "Switch Manager" it's no longer under `Action` - instead right click the computer name (in the left area)

Comment: I've done this before and lost internet access. Googled, came here, removed everything and followed these instructions. Lost internet access again because the creation of the switch didn't take over my DNS servers. I had to ncpa.cpl -> WLANswitch properties and manually add them again in IPv4 settings (W8.1 Enterprise x64)

Comment: I couldn't add a new virtual switch to the desired network adapter since I was already bound to a virtual switch and for some reason it doesn't allow more than one binding. It shouldn't be a problem though since te existing binding/virtual switch is already of the type External. The Windows 7 VM still isn't able to access the Internet with it though - but it does recognize the switch.

Comment: I just solved the problem for my part by adding a legacy network adapter to the virtual machine (older network card) - for some reason that made a difference. That is dispite the fact that Hyper-V integration services were already running on the VM, so it shouldn't have been necessary! Well, it was solvable, but kind of a crappy experience.

Comment: best description ever :)

Comment: I tried this on both Wired and wireless connections but get limited connectivity. It's not getting an IP address. DHCP, doesn't seem to be working. If I set manually the IP, DNS, and default gateway on the client, it works.

Comment: One of the best, thoughtful, step-by-step posts I've seen. Thanks for taking the time and effort to put this answer together!

Comment: After adding the virtual network network switch in the Virtual Switch Manager I had to close the Virtual Machine Connection window and the Hyper-V manager window and reopen them. After that I was able to associate the new switch with the VM.

Comment: Creating the new switch worked for me. I was trying to use existing switches and for some reason it was not working.

Comment: excellent, excellent post with clear pictures... I'd stupidly plugged in my network card and forgot to change the source on my switch! running through this I realized, and now have 2 switches that I can _switch_ between (pardon the pun) - I've upvoted this, if I could upvote more I would and also send cake

Comment: THANK YOU for the sudo dhclient bit! I've been tinkering around with my settings for a full day because the external switch just plain wouldn't work, but running those commands from the guest OS fixed it! :)

Comment: The last commands helped me out.

Answer (score 23):

I had to disable and then re-enable the `Allow management operating system to share this network adapter` under the Virtual Switch Manager.

If this isn't checked the host machine will not be able to use the chosen adapter.  It had been checked in my case, for some reason I had to flip it back and forth again.

Comment: I had to disconnect & connect my wireless connection after disable & enable step.

Comment: WARNING - Doing this on a remote server will completely kill the connection as soon as you untick this. I found out the hard way :(

Comment: @PiotrKula In that case you do a: `Get-VMSwitch` and then a `Set-VMSwitch -Name <swtch-name> -AllowManagementOS $True` on a powershell console. Just for future reference! ;)

Answer (score 7):

Without rebooting I managed to get it working with a wireless adapter, which otherwise was doing nothing.

Open the network connections control panel

You'll see the virtual adapter setting has created a network bridge.

[image]

Right click on your Wi-Fi adapter (the one with the signal strength icon) and select `Connect/Disconnect`

Then you have to click the `On` switch that comes up in the sidebar and select your network. For some reason it was `Off` even though I was online before.

[image]

Everything then magically lit up and I was able to access the internet from within my Win XP VM immediately.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Another trick as detailed in this question [Windows 8 Hyper-V network not working on host](https://superuser.com/questions/531590/windows-8-hyper-v-network-not-working-on-host?lq=1) is that this may not work over wireless... re did the setting several times nothing - set up an ethernet adapter - worked straight away. [quick edit to say of course I'd set up separate virtual switches for the two physical adapters...]

Answer (score 6):

Recent Hyper-V versions have a virtual adapter called "Default Switch", that is preferable to be used by the VM. It does a complex internal routing to allow machines to work. Just connect your VM's to it and it should work.

**Alternatively** to connect the VM to the Internet via a WiFi network you can use an "Internal" Virtual Switch. On the screenshot I use Ethernet, but it works with WiFi too. Internal switches do not expose your VM to the Internet, so they is the best solution in general.

Basically you need to create an Internal virtual switch and connect your VM's adapters to it, then use the OS's **Share internet connection** feature.

All steps in screenshots:

[image: Create internal switch]

Then from Adapters in Control panel share your Internet connection (any adapter works).

[image: Share Internet connection]

Sometimes (usually after Windows update) the VM loses the connection although everything seems properly setup. In such case you need to turn off the Internet sharing and then enable it again. You don't need to restart.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me! I spend hours trying to installing and uninstalling Hyper-V and Docker. Thank you!

Comment: This completely killed the connection to the hyper-v server, thanks.

Comment: > Sometimes (usually after Windows update) the VM loses the connection although everything seems properly setup. In such case you need to turn off the Internet sharing and then enable it again. 
Did you try that?

Answer (score 5):

In my case, while the VM was running I changed the virtual Switch settings to “Not Connected” and then back to my newly created virtual switch. Worked.

Comment: "Hullo, IT! Have you tried plugging it off & on again?"