# No network connection on Host or Guest simultaneously with Client Hyper-V + Windows 8

Tags: networking, hyper-v

I create a virtual switch from the Hyper-V manager, then I set it as the Network adapter in the VM's settings.

In subsequent attempts, this happens:

- The VM gets access to the internet, but the host OS doesn't

  OR:
- The host OS has internet access, but the VM doesn't.

That is, the host and guest don't get internet access simultaneously.

What can I do?

I did all the steps as indicated in: [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/469806/windows-8-hyper-v-how-to-give-vm-internet-access).

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable "Allow management operating system to share this network adapter".
But it seems that there is a bug. If you create an external network connection with this check mark set then only your guests have internet connection.
uncheck this feature, apply settings  and than redo.

Check > Apply > uncheck > Apply > Check > Apply.
I tried to get this working for several hours. Thanks microsoft for this bug.

Comment: Thank you! I was having the same issue with Hyper-V on Windows 10, and your solution fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set **`Allow management operating system to share this network adapter`** on the external nic?

Look at following screenshot from the [link](https://superuser.com/questions/469806/windows-8-hyper-v-how-to-give-vm-internet-access) you provide

[image]

**Check mark** right below the network card drop down box.