# share internet with guest in mac-filtered lan with static ip addresses

Tags: networking, hyper-v, static-ip, connection-sharing

I have ubuntu 12.04 lts installed in an hyper-V virtual machine, and I want that it can connect to the Internet.

I'm in a lan with mac-filtering and which gives static ip addresses.

What do I have to do?

Addendum: I did all the steps done in: [Windows 8 Hyper-V - how to give VM internet access?](https://superuser.com/questions/469806/windows-8-hyper-v-how-to-give-vm-internet-access) but it did not help.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is mac address filtering, probably your VM mac address is not registered, so that your DHCP server will not issue your VM a proper private IP address.

What you have to do in this case is to check the MAC address of your ethernet interface in the VM, and insert it into the list of allowed MAC addresses in the router.

If you do not have access to the router, then you will have to look-up how NAT connection between host and guest works in Hyper-V. If you do not know how to do that, [here](http://blog.areflyen.no/2012/10/10/setting-up-internet-access-for-hyper-v-with-nat-in-windows-8/) you will find a good guide.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this guide is very well explained. But the drawback is, that it doesn't help me. The VM has no Internet, despite it is in the Network and I can see all my public Folders from the Windows machine, but it doesn't have Internet. Is it possible, that the mac-filter bars the VM from having Access to the Internet?

Comment: Can you do me a small favor? Inside the VM, issue this command, ping -c3 8.8.4.4, and tell me the output, pls.

Comment: I would like to, but I have a small Problem: I removed the virtual Switch (which I added according to your posted guide) and now I can't reproduce the Setting. Even when I go step by step according to the posted guide. When I go `control panel` -> `Network connections` I see this Adapter, but it says: "not identified network". So I don't have Network Connection in my VM...