# Hyper-v : Can't ping physical network after creating Virtual switch

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012

I have a server with 4 nics running Server 2012 R2. I have created a nic team containing all 4 adaptors.

I have then installed Hyper-V server. It has 2 Server 2012 R2 servers on it as VMs.

I have created a virtual switch using the teamed nic mentioned above.
I have ticked the box to share the virtual adapter with the management OS.

The host server has an ip address of 192.168.100.1.
The VM servers have ip address of 192.168.100.10 and 11 respectively.

My problem is that I can't seem to connect the VMs to the physical network. I can't ping 192.168.100.10 or 11 from 192.168.100.1 or vice versa. I also can't ping the router from the VMs.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look at this previously-asked question to see if you've missed anything: http://superuser.com/questions/469806/windows-8-hyper-v-how-to-give-vm-internet-access

Comment: Any relevant events logged on the host?

Comment: Yes I have done all of that.

I have just noticed that when I do an ipconfig on the first VM I get an ip address of 169.254.*.* address even though the ip address is set as a static address on the nic.

This is obviously not right

Comment: How many NICs do the VMs see?

Answer (score -1):

You need to set your virtual switch to match in the settings of the 2 servers and assign the static IP so its on the same switch just so they can see each other.
Try this and it will be alright