# Attach correct network adapter to Hyper-V

Tags: windows, networking, hyper-v

I have a VM running Windows 7 (x86) and I need to be able to transfer files to it.

Problem is, there is no network adapter attached.  When I try to add one, the only adapter available "Windows Phone Emulator Switch".

[image: Network Adapter Options]

- Which is the correct adapter?
- How do I get it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Virtual Network Manager** to add a network adapter

[image: add virtual network adapter Hyper-V]

Source : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770380.aspx

Comment: That lets me add new virtual hardware, but the options are still only the Phone Emulator.

Comment: Do you get something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mlHm3.jpg) when you click on **Virtual Network Manager**

Comment: No, it just adds another slot in the hardware for me [like this](http://i.imgur.com/5auVS2V.jpg).

Comment: [this](http://superuser.com/a/472854/270195) should help you then

Comment: That does indeed look like what I need, cheers!