# Enabling internet connection on a Windows XP VM in Hyper-V

Tags: networking, windows-10, windows-xp, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I did pretty much the same as described in this question:

[Windows 8 Hyper-V - how to give VM internet access?](https://superuser.com/questions/469806/windows-8-hyper-v-how-to-give-vm-internet-access)

However, I still don't have internet access on the WinXP VM. I tried also by adding legacy network adapter and making it use the created virtual switch.

However, the internet connection is still not available. I can see in the device manager that ethernet device is added but it's missing it's driver (it has a yellow question mark on it)

Answer (score 0):

You don't indicate what version of Windows you're running Hyper-V on. If you're running it on Windows 2012 R2 then based on this article (http://billyfung2010.blogspot.ca/2015/10/using-windows-xp-in-windows-10-by-using.html) it sounds like you should be able to take the vmguest.iso from the C:\Windows\System32 directory and mount that in your Windows XP VM. From there, go into the VM and run the installation from the virtual CD-Rom to install the integration services. Once the Integration services have been successfully installed, power down your VM, remove the regular virtual network adapter, replace it with the Legacy network adapter, and assign the new legacy adapter to your virtual switch.

If you're not running Hyper-V on a Server OS then I don't think that ISO will exist inside of C:\Windows\System32. If not then you'll have to find it elsewhere...