# Windows 8 Hyper-V - how to give VM internet access WITHOUT specifying the ethernet adapter?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, hyper-v

While the [following solution](https://superuser.com/questions/469806/windows-8-hyper-v-how-to-give-vm-internet-access) works fine, you need to choose the ethernet adapter of your host to use in order to access the Internet/Ethernet.

How can you configure hyper-v, in order access the Internet/Ethernet in the same way as the host does? Without specifying a specific physical adapter to access the internet through.

In practice, my issue is the following: At home, I connect my laptop to the internet via WIFI. At work, I connect it to the internet over LAN. Currently I have to change the VMs configuration every time between the WIFI Adapter and the LAN Adapter. How can I avoid this annoying changes?

Comment: IIRC Hyper-V does not support automatic bridging or NAT. Use VirtualBox or VMware Player/Workstation.