# How to share Internet connection between laptop and Hyper-V VM?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I'm new to Hyper-V and have set up a VM on my Win 10 laptop.

To enable Internet access in the VM, I followed [Windows 8 Hyper-V - how to give VM internet access?](https://superuser.com/questions/469806/windows-8-hyper-v-how-to-give-vm-internet-access) and setup a virtual adapter.

The issue is after creating a virtual switch I lost Internet access from the laptop. Is there a way I can keep using same connection on the laptop and the VM preferably without doing changes every time? It's also fine if I have to do small changes.

Comment: IIRC, you need to make sure the switch you created has external access. Like the post you linked, the adapter the switch uses should be either LAN or Wireless, depending on what you use to connect to your network on the laptop.

Comment: @MichaelFrank thanks, I m choosing External and it is a wireless connection. Will I need to do some other settings every time to switch internet or it will be available on both machines automatically ?

Comment: I'm not sure. I've never used a V-Switch on a laptop. I could probably try later on tonight and get back to you.

Comment: There should be a setting in Hyper-V to share the network adapter with the VM and the host. This needs to be enabled for both to have Internet access.

Comment: Try [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/letsdothis/2012/01/08/configuring-hyper-v-for-multiple-subnets-with-only-one-nic-server-2008-r2-edition/) answer.