# Hyper V - Virtual Switch not showing as adapter in VM

Tags: networking, windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v, windows-embedded-7

I am trying to share the network connection from the host (windows 10 pro) but without any luck.

I have created a 'Virtual network switch' to the active wired connection on my Windows 10 PC (an intel ethernet connection).

I have a WES7s (windows7 embedded standard) 'guest' VM running which is used the `network adapter` which is the link to the `virtual switch`.

When I launch my VM, windows 7 boots up nicely, but never gets network connection. When I go to the control panel => network and internet => network connections I get an empty list. No adapter is showing up, windows has no notion of it all it seems.

What else can I try?

Comment: Have you tried this SU answer: https://superuser.com/questions/469806/windows-8-hyper-v-how-to-give-vm-internet-access

Comment: @Kinnectus, thanks for the attempt, but yes I already read that one. The difference is in the fact that he 'had' an internet connection. In my case my VM does not have any notion of an available network adapter.

Comment: In your VM are there any missing devices in Device Manager? You may also look at Integration Services - like the guest extension pack in VirtualBox. There is also the possibility you can try creating a legacy network adapter and see if this gives network to your guest

Comment: Still nothing new. I just installed a Widows 7 Pro VM which has no issues finding the host network adapter. Is it possible to have a Windows7 `Embedded` Standard as VM?

Comment: Try using a Legacy network adapter instead, and link to virtual switch

Comment: @xavier_fakerat can you explain how that works?

Comment: On the VM settings , choose Add Hardware >> Legacy Network adapter >> Connect network adapter to virtual switch. The reasoning behind this is these adapters have different drivers so the it may be compatible with your VM installation.  I had a similar issue with Ubuntu VM and solved this way.

Comment: @xavier_fakerat that's a winner, thx! drop it as answer and i'll accept it as answer.

Comment: Glad its resoled :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the confirmed working solution by @bas:

**Changing the network adapter to Legacy**

On the VM settings , choose **Add Hardware** >> **Legacy Network adapter** >> Connect network adapter to virtual switch.

The reasoning behind this is these adapters have different drivers so the legacy driver may be  the most compatible one with the VM installation.

Comment: Thx a bunch again