# Hyper V - Cannot share internet connection to guest OS Windows XP to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-xp, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I found a great post on Windows 8 Hyper V below, but unfortunately it is not working for me.
[Windows 8 Hyper-V - how to give VM internet access?](https://superuser.com/questions/469806/windows-8-hyper-v-how-to-give-vm-internet-access)

I am using Windows 10 as host and Windows XP as guest OS. Even if I do `ipconfig`, I'm receiving the below screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Click File > Settings > Network Adapter. Make sure the dropdown is the correct virtual switch. If you do not have a virtual switch in the list that is internet capable, then you need to go into hyper-v on the right hand side, choose virtual switch manager, and create an "external" virtual switch. Then, go back to the VM settings menu and add it from the dropdown under network connection.

Answer (score 0):

The default virtual network adapter of hyper-v won't work with Windows XP, you should use add hardware > add legacy adapter in XP's settings and set it as the adapter for the connection.

Comment: Im trying to connect a virtual WinXP machine (on a Win10 machine) to the internet. The solution proposed here does not work for me. I'll be happy to hear if it does for others