# Hyper-V Windows 7 WM: no internet connection

Tags: windows, networking, virtual-machine, internet, hyper-v

I just installed Windows 7 on a virtual machine in Hyper-V and there is no internet connection. What I tried:

1. Creating a new network virtual switch.
2. In the settings for the WM, enabling virtual LAN identification for it.
3. Following [this guide](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/share-an-ethernet-or-wireless-network-connection-with-hyper-v-in-windows-10/), which involved internet connection sharing, which which I had problems.

Also I found [this option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZtnt.png) in the properties of my Wi-Fi adapter, but it didn't resolve the issue. I have a Windows 10 laptop. Thank you in advance.

**UPD:** The answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/469806/windows-8-hyper-v-how-to-give-vm-internet-access) is my first step.

Comment: I am looking at a Hyper-V guest machine here. The host is Windows 10 and wireless. The guest use the Hyper-V Default Switch, no VLAN, no Bandwidth limitations - That is all default. Try removing your network adapter in Hyper-V settings and re-adding as default.

Comment: @John Reverted everything to default - no result. In addition I found out that I somewhy can't add new network virtual switch now. Need to fix that also.

Comment: Perhaps try another guest machine to see if the issue is Guest or Hyper-V